# Deep copy object containing interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class that I would like to do a deep copy on.

```
public class KeyInfo
{
  public KeyInfo(IKeySetup keySetup, IKeyData data)
  {
    KeySetup = keySetup;
    Data = data;
  }

  public IKeySetup KeySetup { get; set; }
  public IKeyData Data { get; set; }

  public KeyInfo DeepCopy()
  {
    var keyInfo = (KeyInfo) this.MemberwiseClone();
    return keyInfo;
  }
}
```

How can I copy the interfaces? Do I have to implement ICloneable for the interfaces and then have every class with one of those interfaces implement Clone()? Is there a way to avoid each class having to implement such a function?

Comment: I suppose your interfaces would want to expose a `DeepCopy` method (rather than using ICloneable as it doesn't infer if it's a shallow or deep copy, nor is it type-safe). How would your `KeyInfo` class know how to deep copy `SomeOtherCrazyIKeySetupImplementation`?  Plausibly you could serialize/deserialize a copy, but that depends on your design and implementations.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Plus, it would depend on if the interfaces are even serializable! Recursive proprties or infinite loop properties would put a dent in the serialization practice =D

Comment: As for the OP, it sounds like you might want to implement structs that implement the interface. That way, as value types, they can be simply copied easier. Dunno if that helps.

Comment: @Tejs Yup. But as I said, if JKF _knows_ the implementations of the interfaces being used, serialization might be a way to do it.

Comment: @Tejs Even as structs, if the implementations of the interfaces contain object references, then they'll be problems.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Good point. I'm curious why the OP needs to a full deep copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no built in way of doing deep copy of an object you must provide your own to be able to do so.

Forcing implementer of `IKeySetup`/`IKeyData` to have DeepCopy by including it in interface may be good idea. Requiring `ICloneable` could be another approach - either compile time (by deriving your `IKeySetup`/`IKeyData` from `ICloneable`) or run-time by trhowing if object does not support `ICloneable`.

Comment: Just to add, if you're going to go the route of having the interfaces implement a cloning method, ditch the `ICloneable` and implement your own `IDeepCloneable` interface with a `DeepClone` method which _tells_ the developer explicitly that you expect a full deep clone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) method to copy objects via emit.